# Question about turtle module and Turtle() class

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm hoping someone could explain to me exactly what is going on here. I imported the module turtle and created (2) variables. The variable 'jim' I set equal to the turtle module that was just imported and I'm able to change the shape and color and do all the turtle things I want.  The variable 'terry' is created as an object of the class Turtle.  So my question is, if I have access to the methods and attributes right from the module, is there any reason to create a variable as an object?  Hope this made sense, I'm just starting out.

```
import turtle
jim = turtle
jim.shape("turtle")
jim.color("orange")
print(type(jim))

terry = turtle.Turtle()
terry.shape("turtle")
terry.color("red")
terry.forward(100)
print(type(terry))

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```